# Ruby and Rails: Adding a column to a model without migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are a number of questions here about adding columns to a model via rails migration files and a rake db:migrate.

In this case, however, the application is basically a CRUD on top of an existing SQL Server database that is generated by another application. That is, I don't control it. Those who do control the database have added several columns to a table.

What I need is for the Rails app to respect the changes made to the database without assuming it has full control over the table structures.

I've tried plugging the new fields into the model and controller files, but sql queries give TinyTDS errors saying the new fields don't exist. Queries by hand (via SQL Server Management Studio) work fine. What am I missing? Why doesn't Rails recognize the new fields when they appear in the table model?

UPDATE:

It turns out that the problem is more subtle than I though when asking the initial question. As background, this application is set up with two databases, one production, one development/test. They are both on the same SQL Server database server. What's actually happening with the missing columns is that the Rails app pulls from production no matter what environment I use. Even when I change both environments to use the same development database (in database.yml), the app continues to query the production database.

Perhaps this is a problem between Rails and SQL Server. I've cleared all caches and cleared all database connections, but it makes no difference. It seems that the Rails app is caching the database name and login info somewhere.

One day I'd like to get this fixed, but for now I'll simply move the development database to another server for testing.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Are the TinyTDS error Rails errors or SQL errors?

Comment: The TinyTDS errors are SQL errors

Comment: Is the information in `schema.rb` what you want after your run `rake db:schema:dump`?

Comment: That was helpful. rake db:schema:dump shows four of the eight columns added to the table, but not the other four. SQL Server Management Studio shows all of them, and I can query all of them in Python without problems. Not sure why Ruby can't see them, but at least it's something to chase down.

Comment: In case it helps, the TinyTDS error is this one (edited):  TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'Third_Email'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT LastName, FirstName, Middle, Primary_email, Secondary_email,Team_Assignment,Third_email FROM [Employee] WHERE (LOWER(LastName) = N''Smite'' AND ImageID = N''000000'' )'  That same SQL, when run through SQL Server Management Studio or Python/Django works fine.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord has a cache of the table fields. If you want to reset the cache for a model without restarting your application, you can do:

```
MyModel.reset_column_information
```

Comment: I restarted the application several times and tried resetting column information, but the SQL call continues to insist that the new columns do not exist, when they do.